# Focusing a window for scrolling

Tags: .net, visual-studio, scroll, focus

I have some experience in Python and Java, but I dont really know the .NET framework and how to interact with Windows.
What I want to do is a little program/script (maybe I need a DLL?) that when I use the scrollwheel on my mouse, the program that is right under the pointer gets focused and scrolled. Sometimes I scroll, and because another program is focused then I have to click on the program and then scroll. Its not that annoying, but I just want to learn how I would accomplish that in Windows environment.

Comment: Are you re-inventing the wheel ? http://ehiti.de/katmouse/

Comment: Yea, I was aware of that, but this is more like a learning project for me. Do you know an open-source project similar to that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not exactly the Katmouse program, but to get a start i suppose you could look at [this](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) and the tutorial for [that](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx)

You might also wanna look at the new System.Reactive stuff in .net 4, i have seen people do some neat things with it. Here's one [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2009/11/18/a-brief-introduction-to-the-reactive-extensions-for-net-rx.aspx)